# Can't change Latitude and Longitude after creating in GeoDjango

Tags: django, forms, latitude-longitude, geodjango

I have a model of store

models.py

```
class Store(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    point = models.PointField(null = True, blank = True)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I set a form to create a store where the latitude and longitude can be converted into a point

forms.py

```
class StoreForm(forms.ModelForm):
    latitude = forms.FloatField(
            min_value = -90,
            max_value = 90,
            required = True,
    )
    longitude = forms.FloatField(
            min_value = -180,
            max_value = 180,
            required = True,
    )

    class Meta(object):
        model = Store
        exclude = ['deleted']
        widgets = {'point': forms.HiddenInput()}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        coordinates = self.initial.get('point', None)
        if isinstance(coordinates, Point):
            self.initial['longitude'], self.initial['latitude'] = coordinates.tuple

    def clean(self):
        data = super().clean()
        latitude = data.get('latitude')
        longitude = data.get('longitude')
        point = data.get('point')
        if latitude and longitude and not point:
            data['point'] = Point(longitude, latitude)
        return data
```

I used this form to add Store in my HTML frontend and when I check my backend data is in there.  this form helps to show latitude and longitude fields and when I submit it automatically converts into a point

When I want to update the store I used the exact same form to update, and I can see the previously added latitude and longitude value in charfield(as usual I used the instance to get the value of fields from that specific entry).

The problem is, I can't update the latitude and longitude now. Why?

NB: if you thinking about exclude and hiddeninput widget, this is the way it works, I trieddd different ways, but this way latitude and longitude is added to form point, in other way it is not converted. If you know how to fix that problem please help me

Answer (score 0):

Through some more research through google I found this solution

in views.py I used this code

```
if form.isvalid():
   form.save()
```

change it into this

```
if form.is_valid():
    f = form.save(commit = False)
    new_latitude = request.POST.get('latitude')
    new_longitude = request.POST.get('longitude')
    x = 'POINT(' + new_longitude + ' ' + new_latitude + ')'
    f.point = fromstr(x, srid = 4326)
    f.save()
```